# Datamapper Clone Record w/ New ID

Tags: database, clone, duplicates, datamapper, records

```
class Item
    include DataMapper::Resource

    property :id, Serial
    property :title, String
end

item = Item.new(:title => 'Title 1') # :id => 1
item.save
item_clone = Item.first(:id => 1).clone
item_clone.save

# => <Item @id=1 @title="Title 1" ...
```

This does "clone" the object as described but how can this be done so it applies a different ID once the record is saved, e.g.

```
# => <Item @id=2 @title="Title 1" ...
```

Answer (score 7):

`clone` is going to give you an object copy, which isn't really what you want - you want to just duplicate the record in the db, correct? The way I have done this with DM in the past is like so:

```
new_attributes = item.attributes
new_attributes.delete(:id)
Item.create(new_attributes)
```

You can also do it in one line:

```
Item.create(item.attributes.merge(:id => nil))
```